# ASP.NET Core Paging help needed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Needed help . So I am currently working on ASP.NET Core  Paging and it's not working properly.it shows me the same result in the pages. I don't know where is the problem :/ Does anyone know how to solve this problem ,here is my code

**Controlor**

```
    public IActionResult Index( int? pageNumber)
    {
        int pageSize = 5;
        var personnels = from s in _context.personnels
                         select s;
        return View(Pagination<PersonnelModel>.CreateAsync(personnels.AsQueryable<PersonnelModel>(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
    }
```

**Pagination Class**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    
    namespace personnelAUTHENTIFICATION
    {
        public class Pagination<T> : List<T>
        {
                public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
                public int TotalPages { get; private set; }
    
                public Pagination(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
                {
                    PageIndex = pageIndex;
                    TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
                    this.AddRange(items);
                }
    
                public bool HasPreviousPage
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return (PageIndex > 1);
                    }
                }
    
                public bool HasNextPage
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
                    }
                }
    
                public int TotalPageNo
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return TotalPages;
                    }
                }
    
                public static Pagination<T> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
                {
                    var count = source.Count();
                    var items = source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                    return new Pagination<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in my sample, it seems that everything works well on my side. I think perhaps the issue is related to the Page links in the View page. Please check whether the link url and page number are correct.

You could also refer the following sample code:

Code in the controller:

```
    public IActionResult EmployeeIndex(int? pageNumber, int? CurrentPage)
    {
          
        int pageSize = 3;
        if(CurrentPage != null)
        {
            pageNumber = CurrentPage;
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = CurrentPage;
        }

        return View(Pagination<Employee>.CreateAsync(GetEmployee().AsQueryable<Employee>(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize)); 
    }
```

Code in the View page:

```
@model Pagination<MVCSample.Models.Employee>
  
<table class="table">
     ...table content...
</table>

@{
    var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
} 
<ul class="pagination">
    <li>
        <a asp-action="EmployeeIndex"
           asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
           class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">
            Previous
        </a>
    </li>c
    @for (var i = 1; i <= Model.TotalPages; i++)
    {
        <li class="page-item @(i == ViewBag.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
            <a asp-action="EmployeeIndex" asp-route-currentpage="@i" class="page-link">@i</a>
        </li>
    }
    <li>
        <a asp-action="EmployeeIndex"
           asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
           class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
            Next
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please check the action method, you could change it to your owns.

Code in the Pagination.cs (based on your code, I just add a CurrentPage property to display the current page number):

```
public class Pagination<T>:List<T>
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; } = 1
    ....
 }
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot ,the Page links in the View page is incorrect